# How to use geom_ribbon()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my example.

```
library(ggplot2)

my_df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6), y_min = c(1,1,2), 
                    y_max = c(7,8,8))
ggplot(data = my_df)+
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = "blue"))+ 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin =y_min, ymax =y_max, x= x), fill = "grey70")
```

I would like to get back something resembling line plot and confidence interval around it, but I am only getting confidence interval (ribbon) not the main line.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Change the order. Put the `geom_ribbon` before the `geom_line` so it doesn't cover up the previous layer. Layers are drawn in the order which you add them to the plot.

Comment: @MrFlick, still the same, I even added `alpha =0.3` hoping to control transparency.

Comment: It can't possibly be exactly the same. Are you sure didn't get an error or anything the second time? The plot should have changed. That doesn't seem possible. You ran `ggplot(data = my_df) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin =y_min, ymax =y_max, x= x), fill = "grey70")  + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = "blue"))`?

Comment: I concur. I ran your code and swapped the two `geom_*`s, and I now see a red line running diagonally through the gray ribbon.

Comment: You are all correct, it looks like I forgot to move plus sign when transposing lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could set `alpha = 0.3` to see the line and change `grey70` to grey `grey12`:

```
ggplot(my_df) + geom_line(aes(y=y, x=x, colour = "blue"))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y_min, ymax=y_max, x=x, fill = "band"), alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12")
```

[image]